# Why dependency is a command in MakeFile?

Tags: makefile

```
#MAKE=make


SHELL=/bin/sh

all lib progs check test _test install uninstall dep depend: _config
    $(MAKE) $@

clean mostlyclean distclean maintainer-clean TAGS: _config
    $(MAKE) $@

_config:
    sh configure

.PHONY: all lib progs test install uninstall dep depend clean mostlyclean     \
    distclean maintainer-clean _config
```

Hello. 
This is my MakeFile in package. 
There is a `_config` in the Dependency section. 
As far as I know, the dependency part is an array of file names, 
however according to above make file `_config` is defined by `sh configure`. 
Why dependency is a command? \

I found in google basic of MakeFile like below. \

```
main.o : main.c defs.h
        cc -c main.c
kbd.o : kbd.c defs.h command.h
        cc -c kbd.c
command.o : command.c defs.h command.h
        cc -c command.c
display.o : display.c defs.h buffer.h
        cc -c display.c
insert.o : insert.c defs.h buffer.h
        cc -c insert.c
search.o : search.c defs.h buffer.h
        cc -c search.c
files.o : files.c defs.h buffer.h command.h
        cc -c files.c
utils.o : utils.c defs.h
        cc -c utils.c
clean :
        rm edit main.o kbd.o command.o display.o \
           insert.o search.o files.o utils.o
```

But my thing is different. \

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question.  A dependency is a file, not a command.  A rule in make has the syntax:

```
<target(s)> : <prerequisite(s)>
        <recipe>
```

In this rule:

```
_config:
        sh configure
```

the `<target(s)>` are the file `_config`, there are no prerequisites (the part after the `:` is empty) and the recipe is `sh configure`.

What this means to make is, "if I need to build the file `_config`, then I can do so by running the command `sh configure`".

Can you be more clear about what exactly you don't understand here?